# Convert and Filter YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.NNN to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Datetime field (SaleDate) like this:

```
2019-11-27 19:19:00.000
```

I need to convert it to:

```
2019-11-27 19:19
```

and then be able to filter it be greater then that Date and Time.

I have tried:

```
convert(VARCHAR,[SaleDate],120) as Date
```

and then tried to filter it as

```
AND convert(VARCHAR,s.collectiondt,120) > '2022-09-30 00:00:00'
```

But it doesn't filter it. I know i cant filter the alias either, and i have tried running it inside a fetched table but the

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The code shown above is product specific.)

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields. (But a date has a year _field_, a month _field_, etc.)

Comment: Always best to specify a varchar length.   Try Select convert(varchar(16),getdate(),120)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag your database. Likely it is SQL server:
To get it as truncated:

```
declare @dt datetime;
select @dt = CAST(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,SaleDate,120),16) AS DATETIME)
from yourTable
where saleId = blahBlah;

-- Then

Select * from myTable
where s.collectiondt > @dt;
```

PS: SQL Server 2022 and later also has DateTrunc().

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely sure which data you actually want, but you can use FORMAT to reduce the second, and compare it with another time

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ([SaleDate] datetime)
```

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('2019-11-27 19:19:00.000'),('2022-11-27 19:19:00.000')
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
SELECT Format([SaleDate], N'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') FROM mytable
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 2019-11-27 19:19 |
| 2022-11-27 19:19 |

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  Format([SaleDate], N'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') > '2022-09-30 00:00:00'
```

| SaleDate |
| --- |
| 2022-11-27 19:19:00.000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wk5bKGFV)

Comment: Not necessary to convert. `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  SaleDate >= '2022-09-30 00:01:00'` will get the same result